# awk variable passed to a field in a file

Tags: awk

I have a problem using an awk variable to insert into a field 2 of a file.  This is my data:

```
data='AAA||CCC|DDD|EEE|FFF'  
ds='BBB'
```

I want to insert the value of variable ds in field 2 of my file. So I written some test code to view the behavior in awk:

```
$ echo "$data" | awk -F'|' -v tmp="$ds" '{print $1}'  
AAA <== that works ... now I try to print my variable  

$ echo "$data" | awk -F'|' -v tmp="$ds" '{print $1 $tmp}'  
AAAAAA||CCC|DDD|EEE|FFF <== output but I was expecting AAA|BBB
```

I also tried this:

```
$ echo "$data" | awk -F'|' -v tmp="$ds" '{print $tmp}'  
AAA||CCC|DDD|EEE|FFF <== output but I was expecting BBB
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In awk, you don't put `$` in front of a variable to get its value like you do in bash. Just put the variable name:

```
$ echo "$data" | awk -F'|' -v tmp="$ds" '{print tmp}'  
BBB
```

The `$` is only used to get the value of a field (as in `$1`, `$2`, etc.). When putting `$var`, the field is based on the numeric value of `var`. If the value of `var` is 7, e.g., `$var` is the value of the 7th field. If `var` is 0 or some non-numeric value, `$var` is the same as `$0`, which is the whole line as you saw in your attempts.